# Parsing command line arguments in c without spaces

Tags: c, command-line

I have a program that parses command line arguments using a while loop. Simply, while iterating through the length of argc, if an argument matches a flag than the next argument is taken as a variable. Now in my assignment we are asked to do this in a way that spaces between flags and integer arguments are optional.

For example if i input -k1 it is the same as -k 1 and 1 is the value stored.
I can't find anything that allows this. The only thing I can think is that if argc is an even number it means that there are no pals between a set of argument and i could use scanf("-k%d",key).

Any helpful pointers for me?

Comment: Match `-`. Get the next character. That is the option flag. If there is anything after that character then the rest is the option value. Do not use `scanf` for command line args. Use the the standard `argc` and `argv` passed to `main`.

Comment: You could try `sscanf(argv[arg], "-%c%d", &flag, &value)` (with `arg` being the argument number you're checking) and if it returns 2, you have the flag in `flag` and the value in `value`... if it returns 1, you have just the flag in `flag` and can read the next argument to get the value.  If it returns anything else, you have a non-matching argument or an error.  This would treat something like "-kabc" the same as just "-k", though.

Comment: @kaylum would that work when arguments are entered as -k 1? or just -k1

Comment: You need to handle both cases. If the string ends with an option flag character then the option value is in the next `argv` entry.

Comment: If you know what to look for (Google search 'getopt public domain at&t source'), you can find a 1985 (pre-standard, non-prototype) version of [getopt(3)](http://www.informatica.co.cr/unix-source-code/research/1985/1103.html) which handles `program -c 1 -d2` etc, where the option string needs to be `c:d:` to say "this program takes options `-c` and `-d`, and both of them expect an argument.  The code is pretty short; it isn't all that complex.  Current versions of `getopt()` tend to be longer, but they're not much more powerful (`getopt_long()` is a different story).

Answer (score 1):

At a POSIX-compatible OS you can use a standart API for that: `man getopt`. It will do all the dirty job to parse the parameters and will provide you a convenient interface to deal with.

Here is a good example for it: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Example-of-Getopt.html#Example-of-Getopt